# SharedWorker Not Working ...much less sharing

Tags: javascript, web, shared

This post is a question which I will answer because I have searched high and low to find an answere to. Its very basic - as basic as you can get when creating a SharedWorker in JavaScript.

I came across an odd problem which has taken me hours to resolve. It was just to get a basic (really) SharedWorker to post a message to the window.

Right now, in my code I am using

```
...
var port = event.source
...
```

Everything else is pretty standard across blog articles/tutorials.

Why won't this work?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted by someone too cowardice to add a comment :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSWER:

I had originally started off on the blog "http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-started-with-web-workers/" to do a hello SharedWorker example. DO NOT USE THIS ARTICLE ONLY!!!

The only problem that was holding me back was the that blog "`var port = event.source`" -- THIS IS INVALID!

USE `var port = event.ports[0]`.

PS. Shared Workers don't have a `window object` so `alert`, `console.log`, etc will not work.

Working code:

***index.html***:

```
`<div>
  <b>Welcome :)</b>
</div>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>`
```

**main.js:**

```
var WorkerIO = new SharedWorker('/js/worker.io.js', 'NDN-Worker');

console.log('WorkerIO:', WorkerIO);

WorkerIO.port.addEventListener('message', function(eventM){
  console.log('OnMessage:', eventM);
}, false);

WorkerIO.port.start();
WorkerIO.port.postMessage('This is a message from the client!');

WorkerIO.port.addEventListener('error', function(e){
  throw new Error('WorkerIO Error: could not open SharedWorker', e);
}, false);


//importScripts();
```

***Worker.io.js***:

```
var ports = [];
self.addEventListener('connect', function(eventC){
  'use strict';

  ports = eventC.ports;
  var port = ports[0];

  port.postMessage('WorkerIO: connected');

  console.log('o************ OnConnect ************o\n\n'
    , '\t ports:', ports, '\n'
    , '\t port:', port, '\n'
  );

  port.addEventListener('message', function(eventM){
    var data = eventM.data;
    console.log('o************ OnMessage ************o\n\n'
      , '\t data:', data, '\n'
    );
    port.postMessage('from "clientPort": ' + clientPort.toString() + ', with love :)');
  }, false);

  port.start();
}, false);
```

Happy coding:)

Comment: clientPort is not defined how are you using it ? :)